# How can I get the last input expression in Dyalog APL?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, read-eval-print-loop, apl, dyalog

I know I can re-execute lines by putting my text cursor on a previously entered line and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but sometimes the output is long and I am wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to recall previously executed expressions to the bottom of the session log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By default, both Windows IDE and the cross-platform RIDE interface have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> assigned to do exactly that. You can press it multiple times to navigate further back in the input history, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate forwards again.

If you don't like these shortcuts, you can customise them: Click the keyboard icon in the language bar (⌨), then find the **BK** and **FD** codes. For each one, click in the field on the right, and press the desired keystroke or combo.

Comment: In Dyalog APL for Linux, what is the keyboard command for scrolling through the input history? I tried to run dyalog through rlwrap but it didn't work.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I believe APL+Up/Down where APL is the key you use to type APL character, often the Windows key.

Comment: With `setxkbmap -layout se,apl -variant ,dyalog` I got AltGr+Up working to recall previous input. Thanks! Maybe it's documented somewhere.

Comment: Yes, among other places, [here](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#UNIX_IUG/Driving%20tty%20Dyalog%20APL.htm).